# SharePoint Workflow - Email Specific Person email depending on a field choice

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I want a workflow that will send a individual a email if a specific option is choose from a list. So if someone choose Access Control Mechanism standard then it would automatically send that persona email. I made a workflow, but it is way to big... there must be a easier way. Screenshot of my workflow at the bottom.

[image]

[image]

Here is the workflow I would like to do with the automatic emailing the policy owner connected to that policy or standard.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create another list assuming called List_Reviewer and create a Choice column called "AGS Security Policy or Standard" and create a People column called "Exception Reviewer" to store the information, then you can design your workflow as the following screenshot:
[image: email workflow]

Comment: I will try it out and I will get back to you.

Comment: How do I make it work with the other form.